Exterior mobile home door strike plate removal
How can I get these out? My deadbolt has broken and all the new locks I try to replace it with will not latch. Also the doorknob will no longer latch so I can’t keep the door closed. I’ve tried unscrewing and trying to move them around but it’s not possible there is no room for them to move. Any help or advice would very much be appreciated.

Given that this is manufactured/mobile home, you may have to dismount the trim to work on these.

The only way to get the striker plates out is to remove the screws and bend the metal with pliers if you have strong hands, or a hammer and chisel.
After you have bent, ( basically compressed) the piece enough you can wiggle it through the opening.
As an aside: I have found that the strikers are usually less a problem than a sagging door from worn or loose hinges.  However I have had the same problem as you and reverted to regular door knobs, locks and striker plates.

I would also want to check for a sagging door before undoing everything.  Just to second your suggestion.

The door is perfectly fine. It’s a metal door and frame. Both the mechanisms in the knob and deadbolt have broken. So we needed to replace and we have bought multiple knobs and deadbolts specifically for a mobile home and none of them will latch to the old plates.
